# split() and rsplit return only single list item

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the code below, printing "reading" variable outputs: "25.00:50.00:72.00".

```
reading = ser.readline().decode()

print("VALUE: "+reading.split(':')[0]) # this works printing "25.00"
```

Problem is if I try to print 2nd ([1]) or 3rd ([2]) element I get this error:

```
print("VALUE: "+reading.split(':')[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

**Edit 1:**

After examining the "reading" variable I discovered a blank line is also present. Fixed this with this code:

```
reading = ser.readline().strip().decode()
```

I still get the same error, what else could I do to clean up the string? Note: the string is coming via serial if that matters.

**Edit 2:**

The problem was actually with the reading variable like many comments suggested. I was getting the error because the first few times the value for reading variable returned from serial port was actually empty which wasn't directly visible in the console when printed. Checking the length is correct before parsing the date solved my issue.

Comment: Works fine for me, I am not able to re-produce the same error.
`"25.00:50.00:72.00".split(':')-->['25.00', '50.00', '72.00']`

Comment: It works for me. `ser.readline().decode()` obviously does not return `"25.00:50.00:72.00"`.

Comment: Sounds like you are reading an empty line..

Comment: @MartijnPieters Then his first snippet wouldn't work as expected.

Comment: @arshajii: Yes it would. `str.split()` always returns a list with at least 1 element. `''.split(':')` returns `['']`. And an empty line would be `'\n'`, resulting in `['\n']` after splitting.

Comment: @MartijnPieters *"this works printing 25.00"*

Comment: @arshajii: this is not the whole code. I am assuming there is a loop involved somewhere.

Comment: @arshajii `"25.00".split(':') -- > ['25.00']`, looks like the string does not contain any `':'`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Indeed, so he is not reading an empty line. Anyway, this is somewhat of a tangent.

Comment: Is it possible that the `reading` you're printing out and the one that's raising the exception are different ones (e.g., you're looking at the line _before_ the one that fails, rather than the one that fails)? An easy way to test that is to wrap the whole thing in a `try:` with `except Exception as e: print("EXCEPTION {} on line {}".format(e, reading)`. Then you'll know exactly which line raised the `IndexError`.

Comment: print (reading) outputs "25.00:50.00:72.00" but it also outputs an empty line, that must be my problem.

Comment: @DominicM post that output in question body.

Comment: @DominicM What would help most is if you could produce some standalone code that results in the same error.

Comment: See edit. It is indeed an issue with the reading variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is correct.

```
>>> reading = "25.00:50.00:72.00"
>>> print("VALUE: "+reading.split(':')[0])
VALUE: 25.00
>>> print("VALUE: "+reading.split(':')[1])
VALUE: 50.00
```

The `reading` variable does not contain what you think it contains.